# How to run 2 Queries inside a stored Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-function

I'm New to Functions in SQL and am hoping for some Guidance.  I have a Function in SQL that i'd like to add another query to, but I can't quite figure out how to make it happen.

My current function is:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.CountVisits
(@startdate Datetime,
 @enddate Datetime,
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN       
       SELECT     
          COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Number) AS TotalVisits
       FROM         
          Invoice_Tb
       WHERE 
          dtcreated >= @startdate 
          AND dtcreated <= @enddate 
          AND Service_Id = '1'
```

Current output:

```
Total Visits
------------
    15
```

This will return "TotalVisists" where the service ID is 1. Now, let's say I want to also include "Total Visits" I know I can do two queries, inside a query. But is there a way to break this out within the Function to run another query, and put it all together as part of the output?

My second query would be something like:

```
 SELECT     
     COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Number) AS TotalVisitsALL
 FROM
     Daily_TB
 WHERE
     dtcreated >= @startdate 
     AND dtcreated <= @enddate
```

Output I want:

```
Total Visits     TotalVisitsALL
--------------------------------
     15                300
```

Comment: your both query look like identical, how they are different?

Comment: I just edited My question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using both of your queries, in an inline table-valued function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.CountVisits
(@startdate Datetime,
 @enddate Datetime,
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN
    SELECT
      (SELECT     
         COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Number) AS TotalVisits
       FROM         
         Invoice_Tb
       WHERE 
         dtcreated >= @startdate 
         AND dtcreated <= @enddate 
         AND Service_Id = '1') AS TotalVisits,
      (SELECT     
         COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Number) AS TotalVisitsALL
       FROM
         Daily_TB
       WHERE
         dtcreated >= @startdate 
         AND dtcreated <= @enddate) AS TotalVisitsALL
```

Using a multi-statement table-valued function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.CountVisits
(@startdate Datetime,
 @enddate Datetime,
)
RETURNS @tvData TABLE (TotalVisits INT, TotalVisitsALL INT)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @TotalVisits INT, @TotalVisitsALL INT;

  SELECT
    @TotalVisits = COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Number)
  FROM         
    Invoice_Tb
  WHERE 
    dtcreated >= @startdate 
    AND dtcreated <= @enddate 
    AND Service_Id = '1';

  SELECT     
    @TotalVisitsALL = COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Number)
  FROM
    Daily_TB
  WHERE
    dtcreated >= @startdate 
    AND dtcreated <= @enddate;

  INSERT INTO @tvData(TotalVisits,TotalVisitsALL)
  VALUES(@TotalVisits,@TotalVisitsALL);

  RETURN;
END
```

This second way is a multi-statement table valued user-defined function (MSTVF). The main differences with the inline version, regarding to the code structure, are:

- In the returns part, you have to declare a [table variable](http://odetocode.com/Articles/365.aspx), which will be returned by the function. It defines the structure of the table to be returned.
- In the body you can specify multiple statements, except side-effecting or time-dependent operators (unless you do some dirty hacks and jump over some rules).
- You have to insert your results to be returned in the table variable. The insert is done in the same way as in a "common" table.
- You have to put a `RETURN` statement at the end of the process, but without any value to return.

Comment: can you expand a little on the @tvData a bit.  I like this, Would just like to understand how it works.

It looks to me like you just treat it like a variable, then insert it into the "table" at the end?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Conditional Aggregate` to count the rows based on the condition.Try this..

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT CASE
                        WHEN dtcreated >= @startdate
                             AND dtcreated <= @enddate
                             AND Service_Id = '1' THEN Invoice_Number
                      END) AS TotalVisits,
       Count(DISTINCT CASE
                        WHEN dtcreated >= @startdate
                             AND dtcreated <= @enddate THEN Invoice_Number
                      END) TotalVisitsALL
FROM   Invoice_Tb
```

Or simply

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(DISTINCT Invoice_Number)
        FROM   Invoice_Tb
        WHERE  dtcreated >= @startdate
               AND dtcreated <= @enddate
               AND Service_Id = '1') AS TotalVisits,
       (SELECT Count(DISTINCT Invoice_Number)
        FROM   Invoice_Tb
        WHERE  dtcreated >= @startdate
               AND dtcreated <= @enddate) AS TotalVisitsALL
```

Comment: You need an alias for the 2nd subquery.

Comment: Downvoter please comment whats wrong in the answer so that i can improve